# How to process CSV records in which each field is having multiple constraints

Tags: java, csv, string-parsing, opencsv, supercsv

I am working on a requirement where I need to parse CSV file records . Each record can have upto 10 fields and for each field there are multiple constraints(should be required field,alphanumeric,numeric etc).

I have to validate each field against constraints and if it passed all validations that should be saved as successful record in db. Otherwise the record should be saved as failed record, And all the relevant filed level errors should save in some other table with record Id.

Please suggest Good CSV parser with default field level processors to validate them. The parser should allow to define multiple field level processors to handle multiple constraints.

Comment: Have you looked at any parsers?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no issue using Spring-related artifacts, I would likely suggest using Spring batch.

You can easily setup a CSV file reader that will read, parse and provide you with each row.  Upon successful validation, you can pass the valid records to an item writer that will persist them to your data store.  For those records which failed, you can perform other operations as needed.

The great part is most of the framework already exists and it's merely a matter of you wiring the necessary components together for your business use case.

Comment: We are implementing this functionality for struts2 based project. Please suggest any other solution

Comment: also I have to save failed records in database with fail status when user wants to see failed record details I need to display them on webpage with their values and errors..suggest me best solution for this

Answer (score 0):

If Spring batch is not the answer then both openCSV and SuperCSV both support POJO translation.  I prefer this method because if the csv file is coming from potentially multiple outside sources you cannot trust that all columns will be present and/or the order of the columns in the file.

You create a java object with fields with the same names as the column headers.  Since you will be doing your own checking then make them all String.  In the same POJO have a boolean method for each field (isField1NameValid, isField2NameValid.... isFieldNNameValid) this way you can have custom validation for each field.  And then have a method isAllFieldsValid that does an logical and on all fields.

Then you can read the csv file into the POJOs and based on the result of isAllFieldsValid you can write the values into the good file or the bad file.

I have no experience with SuperCSV but with openCSV you can download the source code and see an example of what I am talking about in the HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategyUserTest.

Hope that helps.

:)